# Error jQuery(domChunk).live is not a function

Tags: jquery

> Error: jQuery(domChunk).live is not a function Source File:
>   http:///wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20110528
>   Line: 26

This is the function:

```
//add thickbox to href & area elements that have a class of .thickbox
function tb_init(domChunk){
    jQuery(domChunk).live('click', tb_click);
}
```

Using jQuery version 1.6.1.
Is there any way around this error?

Comment: Sounds like your passing in a "domChunk" that's not a "domChunk"

Comment: The "domChunk" being passed is "a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox" according to firebug.

Comment: It is showing as version 1.2.6
Seems quite old.

Comment: The version in the folder above (wp-includes/js/jquery) is 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery(domChunk).bind instead

Answer (score 0):

To fix thickbox.js replace the tb_init() function with the one below - this will support all versions of jquery! It checks whether on() function exists, if not it will fallback to live().

```
function tb_init(domChunk){
    if($.isFunction($domChunk).on))
    {
        $(domChunk).on('click', domChunk, function(){
            var t = this.title || this.name || null;
            var a = this.href || this.alt;
            var g = this.rel || false;
            tb_show(t,a,g);
            this.blur();
            return false;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(domChunk).live('click', function(){
            var t = this.title || this.name || null;
            var a = this.href || this.alt;
            var g = this.rel || false;
            tb_show(t,a,g);
            this.blur();
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```